# Looping over array elements, given an array of arrays' variable names in Bash Script

Tags: bash, shell

I have an array containing names of categories

```
categories=( categoryA categoryB categoryC )
```

Each category contains multiple products, which is stored in different arrays.

```
categoryA=( productA1 productA2 productA3 )
categoryB=( productB1 productB2 productB3 )
categoryC=( productC1 productC2 productC3 )
```

I want to loop over all products, so I wrote this code:

```
categories=( categoryA categoryB categoryC )

categoryA=( productA1 productA2 productA3 )
categoryB=( productB1 productB2 productB3 )
categoryC=( productC1 productC2 productC3 )

for category_name in "${categories[@]}"
do
    echo $category_name

    category=${!category_name}
    for product in "${category[@]}" 
    do
        echo -e '\t' $product
    done

    echo -e '\n'

done
```

I expected the output to be:

```
CategoryA
    ProductA1  
    ProductA2
    ProductA3

CategoryB
    ProductB1  
    ProductB2
    ProductB3

CategoryC
    ProductC1  
    ProductC2
    ProductC3
```

but unfortunately, the output is

```
CategoryA
    ProductA1  

CategoryB
    ProductB1  

CategoryC
    ProductC1
```

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [Inian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43092123/6394138) doesn't work for you because your are using a version of bash older than 4.3 (where the support for nameref variables was introduced), you can go for the following solution:

```
categories=( categoryA categoryB categoryC )

categoryA=( productA1 productA2 productA3 )
categoryB=( productB1 productB2 productB3 )
categoryC=( productC1 productC2 productC3 )

for category_name in "${categories[@]}"
do
    echo $category_name


    array_declaration="$(declare -p $category_name)"
    # "$array_declaration" expands to the command that can be (safely)
    # evaluated to recreate the $category_name variable 

    # change the variable name in the array declaration and eval it
    eval "${array_declaration/#declare -a "$category_name"=/declare -a category=}"

    for product in "${category[@]}"
    do
        echo -e '\t' $product
    done

    echo -e '\n'

done
```

Note that reliance on `eval` in the above code should be safe, since the output of `declare -p` is properly quoted.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely do *NOT* use `eval` for this case, just use `declare` to create variables on the fly,

Just replace the line

```
category=${!category_name}
```

in your original answer with

```
declare -n category="${category_name}"
```

the above `declare` syntax will create a reference for `category` to the variable `category_name` which can be accessed further for expanding as an array.

---

`declare -n` is a relatively newer syntax available since introduced in `Bash 4.3-alpha`

Comment: I am getting the following error with this solution: main.sh: line 11: declare: -n: invalid option declare: usage: declare [-aAfFgilrtux] [-p] [name[=value] ...]

Comment: @AshrafBashir: Refer my update in the answer, it needs a version `4.3` or greater.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks, after the update I got the point, what about < 4.3 is there an alternative to eval ?

Comment: @AshrafBashir: `eval` is not recommended to use for safety considerations. If you don't have any maintainability problems, suggest upgrading your `bash` version

Answer (score 0):

I already found a solution,

instead of `category=${!category_name}` , 
I can eval the array `eval category=\( \${${category_name}[@]} \)`

for those who are interested, here it is:

```
for category_name in "${categories[@]}"
do
    echo $category_name

    eval category=\( \${${category_name}[@]} \)
    for product in "${category[@]}" 
    do
        echo -e '\t' $product
    done

    echo -e '\n'

done
```

I will leave the question and the answer, for whoever meets the same challenge, and for anyone who has a more elegant solution, or for any objections

---

**UPDATE:** For security considerations, check Inian's response, and if you use Bash < 4.3 as I do, check Leon's response as an alternative

Comment: can you explain a bit what does this eval do?